# EF tracking changes in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

im using Entity Framework6 in my solution, and now i need to track changes in database but cant figure out how to do it. 
Is there a way to track changes in database using Entity Framwork?

***update***:
I've found this solution, its using SqlDependency in the way that allows to use it With Entity framework.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server

Comment: Yes, SqlDependency Class enables monitoring data changes in the database. Here is an example - http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/c-sqldependency-monitoring

Comment: You mean changes in the schema or data?

Comment: @GiorgiZautashvili, database tracking, not tracking that ObjectStateManager does.

Comment: Ah, yes, RefreshMode.StoreWins does the trick. It would be great if you added comment to your post and marked it as an answer, so that others also know that it has been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this solution, its using SqlDependency in the way that allows to use it With Entity framework.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the [SaveChanges()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges.aspx) method to track the changes. Here's some example out of one of our applications:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>();
    if (entries != null)
    {
        foreach (DbEntityEntry<IAuditable> entry in entries)
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.SystemFields = new SystemFields
                    {
                        SysActivityCode = ActivityCode,
                        SysCreationUser = UserId,
                        SysCreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                    };
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.SystemFields.SysModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    entry.Entity.SystemFields.SysModificationUser = UserId;
                    entry.Entity.SystemFields.SysActivityCode = ActivityCode;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

where `SystemFields` is a `ComplexType` added to all entries which implement the `IAuditable` interface:

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// System fields who contain change and status information
    /// </summary>
    SystemFields SystemFields { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class SystemFields
{
    /// <summary>
    /// When has this entry be created
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public DateTime SysCreationDate { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Who has created the entry
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string SysCreationUser { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// When has this entry been modified
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? SysModificationDate { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Who has updated the entry
    /// </summary>
    [CanBeNull]
    public string SysModificationUser { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Which activity has created/changed this entry
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public string SysActivityCode { get; set; }
}
```